# Facebook Graph API "Like" Edge Limited to 25 Likes

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using the Facebook Graph API V2.10 explorer(https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%2Fposts%3Ffields%3Dlikes&version=v2.10), I was able to figure out how to get who liked my posts for a personal project with this request: me/posts?fields=likes

However, I noticed that it only shows the first 25 people who liked my post rather than the list of 85 people who did like my post. Is this a limit of the API or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read about "Traversing Paged Results" in the docs:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api#reading

Comment: Thanks! I had to set the limit parameter to a higher number. By default, it is set to 25

Comment: keep in mind that you may still not get ALL entries, traversing paged results is the better way to get all items. you should not set the limit too high either.